# Custom Tabs in Salesforce

Tags: community, custom-object, custom-button, custom-field, standard-objects

I have a custom app named "**Home Solutions**" in **Lightning Version of Salesforce**. I created another custom object on Sales app named **School Details** (standard app available by default in SFDC) also I created another custom object on **Solar Energy app** (custom app used) named **Solar equipment Details**>

My question is whenever I create an object and make it private to a particular app and then create a custom tab for it. I can see the custom tab on my Custom apps, the visibility doesn't hide to a particular app.

Org wide defaults are set to private for **School Details** custom object. I am not able to figure out why all the private tabs of other objects are visible on my custom app.

Comment: There could probably be quite a few similar questions already answered on this forum, which you could search. I guess you are bit confused between record sharing and tab visibility. Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tab visibility can be managed from profile or permission sets. This [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325081&type=1&mode=1) should answer your question. *Org Wide Default settings is not to be confused with tab visibility, since it serves a different purpose mentioned at the end of this answer. I recommend you read thru developer guides or trailhead modules to understand more about how object, record & tab is access managed in Salesforce.*

Following points should clarify your confusion about tab visibility.

1. While creating a custom object tab, its visibility is not explicitly defined; so, it's basically available to be included in the all the apps within the SF org.
2. From App Manager, you could edit an app and include the custom object tab in it as well as define which profiles can access that app. This action restricts app visibility by profile and lists the tabs made available in an app. So, it doesn't explicitly restrict the tab visibility from app launcher or rather is not exclusively meant for controlling tab visibility.

Tab visibility can be (& should be) defined at object level in profiles or permission sets, thereby making a custom object tab visible or hidden from an user, as shown in the table & ref screenshot below (*SF reference can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=permissions_tab_settings_ref.htm&type=5)*)

|  | PERMISSION SETS | PROFILES | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Available | Default Off | The tab doesn’t appear in an app’s navigation bar, but it is available in the App Launcher in Lightning Experience and on the All Tabs page in Salesforce Classic. Individual users can customize their display to make the tab visible in any app. |
| 2 | Available and Visible | Default On | The tab appears in an app’s navigation bar. The tab is also available in the App Launcher in Lightning Experience and on the All Tabs page in Salesforce Classic. Individual users can customize their display to hide the tab or make it visible in other apps. |
| 3 | None | Tab Hidden | The tab isn’t available in the App Launcher or the All Tabs page, isn’t visible in any app navigation, and is excluded from API responses. |

[image]

I would recommend to read [custom tab considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_tab_considerations.htm&type=5) as well.

---

*Org Wide Defaults' (OWD) purpose is to define the level of access to records that user doesn't own and is not meant for defining the visibility of the custom tabs. For additional sharing beyond the following OWD setting, you would have to use Role Hierarchy, Sharing Rules & Manual Sharing.*

1. *Private: No Access to the object records that the user doesn't own or didn't create.*
2. *Public Read Only: Only read access to all the object records that the user doesn't own or didn't create.*
3. *Public Read Write: Both read & write access to all the object records that the user doesn't own or didn't create.*